# On $x^3-y^2=1728 \text{ unit}$ in number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Consider solution of 
$$x^3-y^2=1728 \text{ unit} \qquad (1)$$ 
in a number field.

This is related to the discriminant of elliptic curve
in terms of $c_4,c_6$.

Via elliptic curves it might have infinitely solutions
for fixed unit.

I am interested if $x,y$ are in the ring of integers
of the number field.

If one solution exists, scaling by powers of units
gives infinitely, so define a set of solutions
to be primitive if the norms of $x$ are distinct.

> Q1 Does (1) have infinitely many primitively solutions
>   when $x,y$ are in the ring of integers?
>
> Q2 Does positive solution to Q1 contradicts the
>   abc conjecture over number fields?
>
> Q3 What is the expected abc quality of triples
>   resulting from (1)? Say for $w=\sqrt{2}$, `A= (w + 1) * 3^3 ;B= (-70*w - 99) * w; C= (-2*w - 1)^4, A+B+C=0`

I suppose this is impossible since it might solve $x^3-y^2=u^n$
for many $n$.

Comment: The equation $y^2 = x^3 -1726\,u$ for a fixed unit $u$ is an elliptic curve and so it has finitely many integral points by Siegel's theorem. So I read the question as asking to find solutions when $u$ is allowed to vary in all units.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich indeed, $u$ varies in infinitely many units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always absorb 6th powers into $x$ and $y$, so there is a finite set of units $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ (covering the congruence classes of units mod 6th powers), so that every solution to $x^3-y^2=1728u$ with $x,y\in\mathcal{O}_K$ and $u\in\mathcal{O}_K^*$ yields a solution $(X,Y)\in\mathcal{O}_K\times\mathcal{O}_K$ to one of the finitely many equations $x^3-y^2=1728u_i$ with $1\le i\le n$. Each of these finitely many equations has finitely many solutions (by Siegel). From this it is easy to answer your question, Start from the finitely many solutions $(X_j,Y_j)$ with $1\le j\le N$, 
then the full set of solutions to your equation is 
$$
  \{ (v^2X_j,v^3Y_j) : 1\le j\le N\quad\hbox{and}\quad v\in\mathcal{O}_K^*\}.
$$
Since the units have norm 1, there are only finitely many solutions with distinct $x$-norms.

Comment: I still don't understand why the _infinite_ set $u_i$ must have finitely many solutions with distinct norms. If you take _finite_ sets $u_i$, the set of integral points is clearly finite.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}^*_K$ modulo $6$-th powers is a finite group.

Comment: Related question about FLT:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357338/flt-and-integral-points-on-elliptic-curves