# FLT and integral points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

For integers $x,y,z,t,n$ define $S_n : xy(x+y)=t^n$.

For $ n > 2$, Fermat's Last Theorem implies there are no integral
solution on $S_n$ with $x,y$ coprime and $xy(x+y) \ne 0$ since $x,y,x+y$ are
n-th powers.

For fixed $t,n$, $S_n$ is elliptic curve and it might have infinitely
many rational solutions.

> Q1 Do we have elementary constraints on the coprime solutions
>   of $S_n$?

Partial results.

Solving symbolically, for $y=y_0^n$ we have $4t^n y_0^n + y_0^{4n}=y_1^2$
over the integers.

Homogenize $S_n$ to get $S'_n : xy(x+y)=t^n z^3$
and fix $t,n$.

$S'_n$ has the long Weierstrass model $v^2-t^n v = u^3$
and the projective Weierstrass model $E_n : w v( v-t^n w)= u^3$.

The map from $S'_n$ to $E_n$ is $(z,x,(x+y)/t^n)$
and the inverse map is $(v,-v+t^n w,-u)$

The short Weierstrass model is $v^2=u^3+16 t^{2n}$.

> Q2 For $n > 6,t >1$, are there coprime integer solutions $u,v$
>   to the short Weierstrass model?

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160350/on-x3-y2-1728-text-unit-in-number-fields?rq=1